# Highchart word cloud in custom shape

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highchart word cloud on my website and it is working all fine. But is it possible to have the wordcloud in any custom shape?

For example circular or in the shape of a star?

Working code to show a rectangular word cloud:

```js
var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean bibendum erat ac justo sollicitudin, quis lacinia ligula fringilla. Pellentesque hendrerit, nisi vitae posuere condimentum, lectus urna accumsan libero, rutrum commodo mi lacus pretium erat. Phasellus pretium ultrices mi sed semper. Praesent ut tristique magna. Donec nisl tellus, sagittis ut tempus sit amet, consectetur eget erat. Sed ornare gravida lacinia. Curabitur iaculis metus purus, eget pretium est laoreet ut. Quisque tristique augue ac eros malesuada, vitae facilisis mauris sollicitudin. Mauris ac molestie nulla, vitae facilisis quam. Curabitur placerat ornare sem, in mattis purus posuere eget. Praesent non condimentum odio. Nunc aliquet, odio nec auctor congue, sapien justo dictum massa, nec fermentum massa sapien non tellus. Praesent luctus eros et nunc pretium hendrerit. In consequat et eros nec interdum. Ut neque dui, maximus id elit ac, consequat pretium tellus. Nullam vel accumsan lorem.';
var lines = text.split(/[,\. ]+/g),
    data = lines.reduce(function (arr, word) {
        var obj = arr.find(function (obj) {
            return obj.name === word;
        });
        if (obj) {
            obj.weight += 1;
        } else {
            obj = {
                name: word,
                weight: 1
            };
            arr.push(obj);
        }
        return arr;
    }, []);

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    accessibility: {
        screenReaderSection: {
            beforeChartFormat: '<h5>{chartTitle}</h5>' +
                '<div>{chartSubtitle}</div>' +
                '<div>{chartLongdesc}</div>' +
                '<div>{viewTableButton}</div>'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'wordcloud',
        data: data,
        name: 'Occurrences'
    }],
    title: {
        text: 'Wordcloud of Lorem Ipsum'
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/wordcloud.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are only a few build-in algorithms, but you can try for example the spiral one.
However, you might also create your algorithm in any imagined shape similar to one I did in the demo below (to try it, uncomment the `placementStrategy`).
More on that in the documentation: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/word-cloud-series#custom-spiralling-algorithm

**API:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.wordcloud.spiral
**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ug1e6sbx/